# Removing varchar(s) after a semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a lot of data like this:

```
pix11co;10.115.0.1 

devapp087co;10.115.0.100

old_main-mgr;10.115.0.101

radius03co;10.115.0.110
```

And I want to delete the stuff after the `;` so it just becomes

```
pix11co

devapp087co

old_main-mgr

radius03co
```

Since they're all different I can live with the semi-colon staying there. 
I have the following query and it runs successfully but doesn't delete anything.

```
UPDATE dns$ SET [Name;] = REPLACE ([Name;], '%_;%__________%', '%_;');
```

What wildcards can I use to specify the characters after the `;` ?

Comment: Hint: `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX`

Comment: Check out: `LEFT`, `SUBSTRING`, `LEN`. Walking out the door or I would offer more help! edit: You're in good hands with WEI_DBA

Comment: That was pretty much it. Thank you so much for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING()` and `CHARINDEX()` functions:

```
CREATE TABLE MyStrings (
    STR VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO MyStrings VALUES
('pix11co;10.115.0.1'), 
('devapp087co;10.115.0.100'),
('old_main-mgr;10.115.0.101'),
('radius03co;10.115.0.110');

SELECT STR, SUBSTRING(STR, 1, CHARINDEX(';', STR) -1 ) AS Result
FROM MyStrings;
```

Results:

```
+---------------------------+--------------+
|            STR            |    Result    |
+---------------------------+--------------+
| pix11co;10.115.0.1        | pix11co      |
| devapp087co;10.115.0.100  | devapp087co  |
| old_main-mgr;10.115.0.101 | old_main-mgr |
| radius03co;10.115.0.110   | radius03co   |
+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `CHARINDEX`? E.g.:

```
SELECT LEFT('pix11co;10.115.0.1', CHARINDEX(';', 'pix11co;10.115.0.1') - 1)
```